# Not allowed to return a function from a function. How could I?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, language-lawyer

`8.3.5/8 Functions [dcl.fct]` says

> [...] **Functions shall not have a return type of
>   type** array or **function**, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things. [...]

Why so explicit of a rule? Is there some syntax that would even allow returning a function as opposed to a function pointer?

Am I miss-interpreting the quote?

```
typedef void (*fp)();

void foo(){}
fp goo()
{
    return foo; //automatically converted to function pointer
}
```

Comment: @B.Nadolson that only counts as an invalid conversion.

Comment: "automatically converted to function **pointer**". Then it's not a function ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a contrived example of a function trying to return a function:

```
void foo() { }

template<typename T>
T f() { return foo; }

int main(){
    f<decltype(foo)>();
}
```

This is the error I get from Clang 3.2:

```
Compilation finished with errors:
source.cpp:7:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    f<decltype(foo)>();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
source.cpp:4:3: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure 
[with T = void ()]: function cannot return function type 'void ()'
T f() { return foo; }
~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: +1: Exactly. Also, this is just one of those rare instances where C++ makes things clear and explicit for us rather than leaving us to derive it from the grammar and other various rules (such as non-copyability). Praise him!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed it is. I often feel like deducing a rule from the Standard is like proving a theorem of Number Theory. Not in this case.

Comment: Yeah; it's interesting that it's rare enough to actually generate an SO question from an alarmed OP when it _does_ happen.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some syntax that would even allow returning a function as opposed to a function pointer?

A syntax? Sure there is:

```
using fun = int (int);

fun function_that_returns_a_function();
```

That doesn’t compile because the rule in §8.3.5/8 forbids it. I don’t know why the rule specifically exists – but consider that the type “function” doesn’t have any size so you cannot create objects of function type in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably does not answer your question completely but it does so partially

You can return a function from another function (that's what lambdas are)

```
std::function<int (int)> retLambda() {
    return [](int x) { return x; };
}
```

Comment: Technically, lambdas are not functions though, they are instances of *functors*