# What is a function type

Tags: c

In C11 specification is cited the term function type as follow:

> A function type describes a function with speciﬁed return type. A
>   function type is characterized  by  its  return  type  and  the 
>   number  and  types  of  its  parameters

But I don't understand if a function type is described only by its return type or also by its parameters.

For example if I have the following function:

```
double bar(int a, int b)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

which is its type?

Comment: `double(int, int)` is the function type

Comment: -1: Your question answers itself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, reading well the answers and better the specification I don't think your answer is correct. So why down-vote?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, well I made that post when you have deleted your question that said that a function type is described only by a return type. And, I don't take any drugs. I don't think you can say that. The respect is important. Greetings.

Comment: In all reality, although I liked the question (because it made me consider the difference between the type of functions, which is rarely used, and function pointers -- @Lightness is right. You wrote the answer in your question. Perhaps you could have been more exact and asked "How do I write that type down?", or "*why* are the parameter types part of the type, what difference do they make?" (which I answered in my answer below).

Comment: @xdevel2000: I haven't written a question on this topic...?! _[edit: oh, you meant **answer**. Yes it was incomplete (not incorrect). I didn't bother to finish it when I realised that it was pointless, as I was just copying words from your question._]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A function type describes a function with speciﬁed return type. A
>   function type is characterized by its return type and the number and
>   ***types* of its parameters**

So, the parameters types are part of the function type. `double bar(int a, int b)` has the same type as `double foo(int c, int d)`, but not the same type as `double foo(int a, double b)`.

You could assign bar to a function pointer like:

```
double (*func)(int, int) = bar;
```

Comment: Please, still one question: so, when the standard says that a function type cannot return a function type or an array type can you make me an example according to what yu're written?

Comment: @xdevel2000 I wasn't aware of that, but this could be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865174/not-allowed-to-return-a-function-from-a-function-how-could-i .

Comment: @xdevel2000 You can return pointers of any type including function pointers from a function, and the type of the return value is part of the function  type.

Comment: Things get even fuzzier with lambdas and the function template in C++11. That template can call anything that doesn't run away fast enough, cf http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function. And in all reality there isn't much difference between functions and pointers to them (much like arrays and pointers). A function can be called through its pointer without explicit dereferencing (what else would you need the pointer for?).

Comment: @xdevel2000: Basically, you can't declare a function that looks like `T f()()` (function returning a function returning `T`) or `T f()[N]` (function returning an array of `T`).  You *can* declare a function like `T (*f())()` (function returning pointer to function returning `T`) or `T (*f())[N]` (function returning pointer to array of `T`).

Answer (score 6):

It's right there in the text you quoted, "and the number and types of its parameters", so yes the parameters matter.

The type  of the example function would be `double (int, int)`, I'm not sure about the notation but something like that.

I.e. "a function that takes two `int` arguments and returns a `double`".

Answer (score 1):

A function type characterize by its return type as well as its number of parameters and type of its parameters. When you declare a function as

```
double bar(int a, int b);
```

it means that `bar` is a function of *type* which accepts two parameters of type `int` and returns a `double` value. You can also understand a function type as

```
double (*fptr)(int, int);
```

`fptr` is a pointer which can hold the address of function type taking two parameters of `int` type and returning `double`.

When standard says that a function type cannot return a function type or an array type, it means

A function can't return functions

```
int f(int ) (int );  //Wrong
```

A function can't return  arrays:

```
int f(int ) [];      //Wrong
```

But, pointer to functions/arrays can be returned from a function.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is, a function is a normal identifier like any other; it's just what it denotes, namely a function, which differs from normal objects. Functions in C/C++ are not objects; they cannot be passed or changed. But function **pointers** can. In that functions and their pointers resemble arrays, to a degree. Another parallel is the pragmatic C approach which almost identifies arrays as well as functions with their location in memory; it's just that we have data here (arrays) and code there (functions).

The type of a function can be obtained like any other type (e.g. `int`, or `int*`) by omitting the identifier from a declaration. That gives you the `double (int, int)` the others correctly mentioned. Each sequence denoting a type has exactly one position where an identifier can be legally inserted (here after the double).

But back to the bottom line: A function name is just an identifier with a type. Let's say we have a function definition in one file and want to use it in another, as is common:

File 1: Normal function definition

```
double external_function(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return a+b;
}
```

File 2: Declare an identifier for that function and use it. Then do something bogus.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare a function type alias (not a pointer type!)
typedef double function_type(int, int);

// Use that to declare that identifier. Not different from 
// any other identifier.
extern function_type external_function;

// Also totally equivalent to the conventional notation;
// it's not harmful to declare the same global identifier
// multiple times.
extern double external_function(int, int);

// Define a function with a different signature, i.e.
// a different type. We'll use it in a joke in main().
double f_float_float(float f1, float f2) 
{ 
    return f1 + f2; 
}

int main()
{
    // Call the previously declared external function: -> 3.
    cout << external_function(1,2) << endl;

    // Do something funny: Declare a pointer to such a function ...
    function_type *function_pointer;

    // ... and assign a function with the wrong type to it.
    // function_pointer = f_float_float; /* doesn't compile: need cast */
    function_pointer = reinterpret_cast<double (*)(int, int)>(f_float_float);

    // Now call it with certain values 
    // (cf. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html)
    // and see what happens.
    cout << function_pointer(0x3f800000, 0x40400000) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```